# What does the map of Earth map look like in the 24th Century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, map

Is there a map of Earth somewhere that shows the various countries that exist during the 24th century? I know it's called United Earth, but I'd imagine it's still divided up into various countries. The ones I've heard mention of are USA, Canada, and France but what others exist at that time?

Comment: There was a massive nuclear war, followed by a mass-invasion from the East. I'd imagine many countries simply ceased to exist as viable political entities

Comment: Indeed, I'm just curious if there's a map somewhere showing what countries are still around :)

Comment: per [memory alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/United_Earth) - "*Even after United Earth was formed, many nation-states and confederations of Earth retained their individual identities. These included the African Confederation, Canada, the European Alliance, Russia, and the United States of America.*"

Comment: There's a map [here](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/8/84/Earth_map.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140326143753&path-prefix=en) but it's rather poor quality. Also Geordi LaForge was born in 2335 in something called the African Federation.

Comment: It looks like a picture with countries on it, but that's not important now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best actual *map* I've been able to find of 24th-century Earth is [this](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Earth_map.jpg) rather poor-quality one from the DS9 episode *Paradise Lost*:

[image: map]

But [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Earth) tells us a few things about what countries existed at the time:

> Even after United Earth was formed, many nation-states and confederations of Earth retained their individual identities. These included ...

- **The [African Confederation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/African_Confederation)**, a political entity with member states including Somalia, in which Geordi LaForge was born in the 24th century. It was preceded by the [United States of Africa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_States_of_Africa), but that was a country in the 23rd century.
- **The [European Alliance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/European_Alliance)**, a political entity based on the earlier [European Hegemony](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/European_Hegemony).
- **The [United States of America](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_States_of_America)**, which still existed as a political entity in the 24th century according to the episode *Imperfection* from *Star Trek: Voyager*.

... and in a less clear category ...

- **[Canada](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Canada)**, a country in North America which was a tourist destination in the 24th century. It's not clear whether its borders are the same in the 24th century as today, nor whether it's a political entity or just a geographical area.
- **[Russia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Russia)**, a country straddling Europe and Asia, where Worf spent some of his childhood in the 24th century. Again it's not clear whether its borders are the same in the 24th century as today (I wonder whether it includes the Crimean peninsula?), nor whether it's a political entity or just a geographical area (as in fact it used to be until the dissolution of the USSR).

Comment: Note the [4747](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s) in the corner!

Comment: Also, Alaska was still a state as of Will Riker's birth.

Comment: I am surprised at the lack of change in coastlines. If global warming continues, there should be significant changes over the next couple of hundred years.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan global warming was found to be a myth in startrek universe

Comment: We have traveled the cosmos. We have united races from dozens or hundreds of planets. We have cured the common cold and eliminated the need for currency. We are still using the Mercator projection.

Comment: Don't forget to give sources for images so we know it's from the show and not just fan art--a reverse image search shows it's [this image](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Earth_map.jpg), a map of Earth's [global security net](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Global_Security_Net) which was shown in the DS9 episode "Paradise Lost"

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan- It could be that they found a way to reverse the process.

Comment: @randal'thor:   This information doesn't mean that both Canada and Russia exist as political entities.   They are equally valid as names of regions.   Just like it wouldn't be unusual to refer to a region as 'Russia' or 'Ukraine' under the USSR.   Or Greenland.  Or Antarctica.   Conversely, you could refer to 'Germany' even when the only political entities were East and West Germany.   The mere mention of a name doesn't mean the countries still exist as countries.

Comment: @ThePopMachine That's fair enough. Would this answer be better with the Canada and Russia paragraphs deleted then?

Comment: @randal'thor:   I would just point out the possibilities.   It's maybe slightly ambiguous.   I believe the context is just the Worf/Riker grew up in Russia/Canada, so it's really not clear.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Edited, thanks.

Comment: (Oops, of course Riker grew up in Alaska, not Canada, as did Ens. Lavelle's grandfather)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Atlantis Project]

This is a screenshot of the [New Atlantis Project](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/New_Atlantis_Project) that Picard was reviewing in the episode *Family*. Perhaps if Picard chose to live below the sea with Louis rather than back on the Enterprise, the Earth would have another subcontinent.

Comment: Strange that the [Hudson Bay](http://mrpolino.pbworks.com/f/1266935208/Hudson%20Bay%20scan.jpg) in Canada seems to be filled in with green...wonder if this was an error by the graphics department or if they really wanted to suggest it had been filled in with land in some previous mega-construction project.

Comment: Florida also looks like it's lost weight according to this map. Maybe a result of global warming/flooding after the nuclear side effects of WW3, or could just be poor resolution of the map.

Comment: @Hypnosifl If you look in the [other portion of the screen](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/2/2a/Atlantis_project.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20050918231845&path-prefix=en) it would indicate that Hudson Bay is more likely a graphics glitch.