# Do any countries in Star Trek no longer exist?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

In the future that *Star Trek* depicts, many nations have changed, such as Africa becoming the United States of Africa. Have any countries fallen victim to this? Options include assimilation into other countries, destruction during the third world war, etc.

Comment: Um, every nation in Africa → United States of Africa?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Earth_countries

Comment: In the future, every country is part of United Earth, except for those that were obliterated during WW3

Comment: @Valorum I love how the USSR comes back into power by the 24th Century (as mentioned in DS9 and VOY, well after our modern version dissolved).

Comment: @Thunderforge - If you live in the Crimea and look out of your window, you can see it happening in realtime.

Comment: @Valorum So there's no confusion, I said I loved it because it seemed like a deliberate invocation of The Great Politics Mess Up ([TV Tropes link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheGreatPoliticsMessUp)), not because of any sentiments of my own towards the real-world country.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I got that :-)

Comment: Check out this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104901/what-does-the-map-of-earth-map-look-like-in-the-24th-century