# How can an address refer to the "USA" if no countries exist in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, geography

In the *Star Trek: Enterprise* episode [Affliction](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Affliction_(episode)), Lieutenant Reed is seen working for section 31 (just a guess, from the fact where the sketchy black coat guy in his chat with Jon asks Jon to read Article 15, Section 31).

In this episode, [Harris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Harris_(Section_31)) asks Malcom to meet at the address he's just sent. In the next shot, we see that Reed has been sent to ([from the transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/91.htm))

> 1044 North Maple, San Francisco, California, USA, Earth. 94-1104-314159

How does the address include USA if Earth does not have countries in Star Trek?

Comment: Section 31 is very, very conservative.

Comment: *Countries* still exist as physical entities, they just no longer function as sovereign states or independant political entities.

Comment: The number of places in the world today that people refer to with names that have zero political significance is huge. In New York City alone there must be more than a hundred places that are just places with names and have no political boundaries at all. Some are very famous, like SOHO and Greenwich Village.

Comment: why do you think countries no longer exist?

Comment: I just don't think this requires explanation.   Mentioning a "country" to specify a geographic location does not imply that it still exists as a political entity.   Furthermore, the existence of a United Earth government doesn't mean that the old countries can't exist as political entites anyhow, just like there are still countries under the UK and EU, and just like most countries still have various political hierachies under them (state/provinces/counties/municipalities etc).   So I just don't see a way that mentioning *USA* contradicts anything.

Comment: I'm sure Scotland still exists as a country, and is still trying to get a Jacobite on the British throne.

Comment: In passing, the tail-end of what looks like an extended ZIP code is the start of pi: `3.14159`.

Comment: I cannot help but notice that the OP is baffled by the mention of "USA", but accepts the mention of "California" without any comment.

Comment: It's an imaginary universe, it should not be surprising that it sometimes refers to imaginary locations like "USA" or "California".

Comment: Do you have any idea how many [San Franciscos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(disambiguation)) there are on Earth?

Comment: The City of Hollywood was disincorporated in 1910, but people haven't stopped talking about Hollywood yet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Enterprise* takes place before the formation of the Federation in 2161. It's still possible that people would identify places by the country that place was in (Paris is both a city in France and a town in Texas, USA). There's no formal date for when the [United Earth government](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Earth) was formed, and the concept might still be new enough people still used old terms at that point, since they would still be understood. From [the episode dialogue](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/91.htm) it's clear the old countries were still well known

> ARCHER: You haven't said much of anything. You've told me a lot about your father, his years in the Royal Navy. Their tradition of honour and service.

The [Royal Navy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Royal_Navy) refers to the military of the United Kingdom. Clearly, that would no longer exist under a United Earth government, so the transition would have had to be within the lifetime of Malcom's father, [Stuart Reed](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stuart_Reed) (we have no detailed information of his life, but it's probable he was in his 50s or 60s).

We also know that the concept of some of the original nations of Earth never really disappeared. In 2267, [the natives of Omega IV worshipped the US Constitution and flag](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Omega_IV_native). Jean Luc Picard was from what was still known as [France](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/France) in 2305.

Comment: We still refer to San Antonio as being in Texas even though Texas is no longer an independent state.

Comment: Omega IV is a bad example as that was a parallel culture duplicate that TOS did several times.  Kind of a twilight zone twist.  No different than an exact replica of Earth in Miri or duplicate Romans.  Even though those are all very impossible.

Comment: @lucasbachmann While TOS had many such "Americana" cultures they came across, this particular one actually worshiped both the Constitution and the US flag. It means  someone had to know enough of said culture to bring those items in the first place, let alone know what they meant.

Comment: An interesting but lengthy discussion about the Omega IV example has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133212/discussion-on-answer-by-machavity-how-can-an-address-refer-to-the-usa-if-no-co); please continue it there instead of in comments here.

Comment: The Royal Navy (and hence concepts of Great Britain/UK) was still in existence in the time of Enterprise, or at least recently enough for Malcolm to have been planning to join it https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Royal_Navy

Comment: TNG:Attached also suggests the United Earth wasn't fully united until 2150.

Answer (score 26):

Although countries no longer had individual governments by the mid-22nd century, at least some of the landmasses were still referred to by their previous names, even as late as the 24th century.

> TROI: So, where have you decided to go?
>
> PICARD: Hmm? What? Oh, er, **France. Labarre. My home village.**
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: The Next Generation* - S04E02 - "[Family](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Family_(episode))"</sub>

> O'BRIEN: Me, out of breath? **I was climbing mountains in Ireland before you were born.**
>
> MUNIZ: You mean hills, don't you? They have gently sloping hills in Ireland. No mountains. But what do I know? After all, you're the mountain man. An old mountain man.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* - S05E02 - "[The Ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ship_(episode))"</sub>

> BASHIR: What did you talk about?
>
> O'BRIEN: A lot of things. His son, Alexander. **Growing up in Russia.** The proper way to eat gagh.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* - S07E01 - "[Image in the Sand](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Image_in_the_Sand_(episode))"</sub>

Comment: For a parallel example here on Earth, look at England: names such as "East Anglia" are still in use, despite the old kingdom of that name being absorbed into the Danelaw back in 869.

Comment: +1. Another example that comes to mind is the episode *Lower Decks*, where Ensign Lavelle mentions a grandfather from Canada (and Commander Riker grew up in Alaska, which both he and Lavelle recognize as being mutually exclusive with Canada).

Answer (score 12):

The other answers are great in pointing out that the names of countries continue to be used even after they have ceased to become independent, sovereign nations.

In our own world, this has happened to many formerly independent nations that have joined with larger ones but retained their old name. Some well-known examples include Texas (1845), Hawaii (territorial annexation in 1898, statehood in 1959), Scotland (1707), and Newfoundland and Labrador (1933).

If Texas and Hawaii can join the USA and still call themselves Texas and Hawaii, I see no reason why the USA couldn't join United Earth and/or the Federation and still call itself the USA.

Comment: Texas still exists. It's the name of a state within the US. Scotland is still a recognised country, separate from England and Wales

Comment: @Valorum true, but Scotland hasn't been sovereign since 1707, but rather subject to the UK. In fact, Scotland had a referendum in 2014 in which they confirmed that they wanted to stay that way (a non-independent country). In the future of Star Trek, the USA presumably still exists but is likewise no longer independent/sovereign, but subject to the rule of the United Earth and/or Federation governments. My whole point is that the USA could continue to exist in such a state, just the same way that Scotland continues to exist.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong, I just think these are terrible examples.

Comment: @Valorum point taken, feel free to downvote my answer if you feel it deserves it.

Comment: I've done worse than that. I've neither upvoted, nor downvoted it.

Comment: "I've done far worse than downvote you, Admiral. I've hurt you. And I wish to go on hurting you. I shall leave you as you left me, as you left her: neither upvoted nor downvoted. Marooned for all eternity in the center of a dead question, buried alive. Buried alive." @Valorum

Comment: In the case of the United States prior to the Civil War the States were much more independent and people probably thought of themselves as Virginians first and Americans second.  The media of the time said "We United States" not singular "The U.S."  European federalism and so on wouldn't wipe out place names.  And by a dictionary definition the governments of star trek are closer to a weak "confederacy" but some folks gave that word a bad name on Earth.

Comment: @Valorum The Texas example is perfect. When Texas changed from a Republic to a state, no-one said "obviously, we need  a new name". In fact, the opposite -- clearly it kept the name. When the country USA joined the world government as an administrative unit(?), same deal.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - Sure, but a thing called Texas continues to exist. People aren't referring to the former country of Texas when they say Texas, they're referring to the State of Texas.

Comment: @Valorum Huh? A thing called the USA continues to exist in Star Trek. And usage seems interchangeable, "the Alamo happened in Texas" or even "Texas became a state in 1846". O'Brien would say "Ireland" for when it was a country, or now when it's whatever StarTrek calls countries in a world government where it's still called Ireland.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - Sure, but you don't hear people referring (except in historical terms) to the likes of the United Arab Republic or Yugoslavia becaise they've stopped existing.

Comment: @Valorum I don't get the relevance. Yugoslavia doesn't exist in any meaningful sense. Some countries won't exist in any way in the Star Fleet Universe. But Egypt has been a part of many empires, but the name and regional identity has existed for four millennia. One could write a future history where the US has been broken up or merged with Canada and Mexico in a world government, but it's plausible, and seemingly likely, that the region keeps the name and identity.

Comment: @Valorum more specifically, both of those broke up.  And the constituent parts championed their own identities.  Can you come up with an example where a country joined a larger one and yet lost its identity?  Within about 100 years?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - Bohemia

Comment: @OwenReynolds: So you're saying that in Star Trek, not only is there a geographical area colloquially called "the USA", but it actually has a government similar to the way US states and/or Canadian provinces have governments today?  i.e. they get to make some decisions the overall government leaves to them, and in turn leave some decisions to municipalities.  Or I guess like for example Germany inside the EU: there's an EU parliament, and a German national government, and German state governments for regions like Bavaria, and municipal governments for each city.  If so then good analogy.

Answer (score 10):

Some official and unofficial maps of the Star Trek galaxy depict space realms like the Federation or the Klingon Empire, etc., spread out over a large proportion of the galaxy.  Maps often depict each realm coving maybe 1 percent to 10 percent, for example.

The Milky Way Galaxy contains at least 100,000,000,000 star systems.  So 1 percent to 10 percent of the volume of the galactic disc of the Milky Way Galaxy would contain at least about 1,000,000,000 to 10,000,000,000 stars, and possibly a few times that many.

So I can imagine that each star system within the Federation has a local system government, and that each group of 10 systems has a second level local government, and that each group of 100 systems has a third level government, and that each group of 1,000 systems has a fourth level local government, and that each group of 10,000 systems has a fifth level local government, and that each group of 1000,000 systems has a sixth level local government, and so on.

Obviously there would probably be many levels of government in a space federation or empire which ruled even one percent of the milky way galaxy.  And there should similarly be several levels of local government within a star system and an inhabited planet within the system.

In the USA there are four levels of government that provide different services.  Municipalities, which usually provide utilities, countries which keep records of wills and deeds among other services, states which make most laws and which issue driver's licenses, and the federal government which fights wars among other things.

In the later Roman Empire there were 5 or 6 levels of government. *Pagi*, subdivisions of *civitates*, *civitates*, which were city states with elected councils and magistrates, provinces with appointed governors, (secular) dioceses with appointed vicars, four praetorian prefectures with praetorian prefects, and the empire as a whole.

So if the United States of America joined the United Earth, presumably some of the functions of the federal government of the USA would be taken over by the United Earth government, but the Federal government would keep some functions, or share some functions with the United Earth government.

And presumably the same thing would happen when the United Earth joined the United Federation of Planets.

So it is perfectly reasonable to assume that the USA still had a functioning federal government with some functions after joining the United Earth and after the United Earth Joined the United Federation of Planets.

Answer (score 8):

You can probably think of an example close to you where one city annexed another, or cities merged, but they still retained the place name as a cultural delineation which no longer carried any legal weight.

Neighborhoods and regions are very real even without legal standing.

In this specific example, a unified Earth still needs administrative regions, though the boundaries may have shifted.

Per [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Earth),

> Even after United Earth was formed, many nation-states and confederations of Earth retained their individual identities. These included the African Confederation, Canada, the European Alliance, Russia, and the United States of America. (TNG: "The Naked Now", "The Price", "Conundrum", "Lower Decks"; VOY: "Imperfection")

So the episode you described is not a one-off continuity error.

See also [What does the map of Earth map look like in the 24th Century?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104901/what-does-the-map-of-earth-map-look-like-in-the-24th-century)