# Clara's and Rose's apartment stairs

Tags: doctor-who

I have just watched the very first episode of the Doctor Who reboot, "Rose", and the flight of stairs she walks down look exactly identical to Clara's stairs in "The Zygon Invasion" episode and Matt Smith's final Christmas episode. Is that intentional or am I wrong or is it just coincidence in Universe not OUT universe?

From series 1 episode 1 "[Rose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wIH-J6xOlc&t=13m9s)":

[image]

From series 7 episode 16 "The Time of the Doctor":

[image]

Comment: In universe, I'm pretty sure Clara doesn't live on the Powell Estate. Out of universe, probably the same film set.

Comment: In-universe, if they both live in the UK's equivalent of public housing, it's not imposible that their apartments were built to the same plan. Public housing tends to be monotonous.

Comment: Updated my answer with some in-universe discussion.

Comment: People seem to forget Doctor Who constantly runs on a very limited budget.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have good news: you're not crazy.<sup>1</sup>

### Both Clara's apartment block and Rose's were filmed at the same out-of-universe location: the [Lydstep Flats](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/locations/lydstepflats) in Cardiff.

Here it is as it appears in the episode *Rose*, with Rose and the Ninth Doctor hurrying down the stairs and through the estate:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And the Doctor Who Locations site confirms that the same location appears in the episodes [*The Zygon Invasion*](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/stories/thezygoninvasion) and [*The Time of the Doctor*](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/stories/thetimeofthedoctor). Here's a Youtube video showing the latter episode, Matt Smith's final Christmas episode, actually being filmed on location at Lydstep:

And another video from the production of Series 9:

Judging from the makeup Jenna Coleman is wearing in this one, she's playing Bonnie (aka "evil Zygon Clara") rather than the real Clara, so this is *The Zygon Invasion* filming we're looking at.

---

### In-universe, they *may* both have lived in the Powell Estate, but it's never confirmed either way.

We know that Rose Tyler lived in the [Powell Estate](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Powell_Estate) in Peckham. We don't know exactly where Clara lived, but she taught at [Coal Hill School](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Coal_Hill_School) in Shoreditch, around half an hour's drive north of Peckham.

There has [been](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/77687162298136764/) [assorted](https://twitter.com/hayleysatweII/status/416212557821538304) [speculation](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:173602), but no confirmation, that Clara and Rose live in the same estate in-universe. The best we can say is that it's *possible*. Since there's been no in-show confirmation, to get more than that you'd have to ask someone like Steven Moffat.

---

<sup>1</sup> No footnote here; but I had you going, didn't I? (Credit to [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/97168/31051) for the joke.)