# Does the number 327 hold any significance to George Lucas?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, george-lucas

In *A New Hope*, the number of the docking bay used to hold the *Millenium Falcon* is 327.  In *The Empire Strikes Back*, the number of the Cloud City landing platform used is also 327.  In *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin, Obi-Wan, and Palpatine are captured in hallway 328. (It's the prequels, so everything has to be different, right?)  And this one's a little shaky, but the last four digits of the trash compactor in *A New Hope* are 3827.  Yep, 3_27.

So is there an actual reason that the number 327 appears multiple times in the *Star Wars* series, or could this just be subtle cross-episode allusion?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/327

Comment: IMDB - 327 - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069704/trivia?item=tr0758116

Comment: Lucas was probably a fan of [this comic strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_327)

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97166/4918 "Why are there so many 47s?" [star-trek]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Probably but not clear what it is

327 is mentioned a lot in Star Wars, so there is obvious some significance.

As well as the Docking Bay on the Death Star and the Landing Platform on cloud city that you have mentioned, there is also the following mentioned in Canon:

- The *J-type **327** Nubian starship used by Queen Amidala* - which had a Nubian **327** hyperdrive core in *The Phantom Menace*
- The *Vulptereen **327*** Podracer that Dud Bolt raced with in The Phantom Menace
- The *Rian **327** Airspeeder* owned by Padmé Amidala in *The Revenge of the Sith*
- Outpost **327** where the shuttle Tydirium was stolen from according to the Junior Novelisation of *The Return of the Jedi*
- The *Hurid-**327** Load lifter* droid at Maz Kanata's in *The Force Awakens*

It also had many further mentions in Legends materials.

The number makes an appearance in Lucas' earlier film *American Graffiti* where the '32 Deuce Coupe had a Chevy *327* engine, this car also had the number plate THX 138 - (a reference to the even earlier Lucas film *THX 1138*

[image: Chevy327Engine]

I cannot remember nor find any mentions of 327 in THX-1138 nor in any Lucas related films after Star Wars (Indiana Jones, Willow etc)

So it appears to be something brought into Star Wars & kept within that universe, unlike THX-1138 which has appeared through most of his works.

It is *possible* that this is a nod to the film American Graffiti, whose commercial success gave George Lucas chance to develop LucasFilm, Skywalker Sound, and Industrial Light & Magic which were all crucial in allowing Star Wars to be made.

---

As an aside the hatch number for the trash compactor *326-3827* is widely reported to have been Mark Hamill's phone number. This has a symmetry with THX 1138 which (using the keypad map of T=8, H=4, X=9) was *849-1138*, George Lucas' telephone whilst at college.

Comment: T = 8, X = 4, 9 = X? Now I'm not a scientist, but that ain't right!

Comment: @Edlothiad ooops good catch, fixed

Comment: Sorry, had to edit. The 9 = X was bothering me a bit too much

Comment: @Edlothiad i didnt even notice that one! maybe I shouldn't try multitasking

Comment: Don't worry, I'll just keep cleaning up after you from now on!

Comment: The [327 was real engine made by Chevy](https://www.opgi.com/blog/2013/12/the-chevrolet-327/). so maybe since the movie helped *power* his career.....